# How to convert svds.m inbuilt function of matlab into vhdl code

Tags: matlab, vhdl

I have been using matlab 2014 and try converting svds.m inbuilt file into vhdl code using hdl coder but it gives error that sparse function not found:

[image: given image shows the error]

The sparse is also inbuilt function but they is no option to add two function in hdl coder together. So is there any other method in converting ??

Comment: Functions supported by Matworks HDL Coder are listed in section 1 of the [HDL Coder User's Guide](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/hdlcoder/hdlcoder_ug.pdf). `sparse` is not listed therein. The User's Guide will also relate you can't pass matrices as input or output ports. What does the 'Open error report' link provide?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is listed as compatible for the VHDL Coder yet it doesn't yield working code you should contact MathWorks for support.